# FOSUserBundle reset password: weird behaviour

Tags: symfony, bundle, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to make my own form for allowing user to edit his profile. I success to add my field at the `FosUserBundle` original fields but I have a weird behaviour.

My user can change his password only one time !! If I retry to change it from the form 2 seconds after (after disconnecting then logging in for example) it doesn't work: every field value can be changed except the password.

EDIT : New information, the new password is save only if i change another field in the form.

Have you an idea about that?

Here is my code:

`UserType.php` in `src/UserBundle/Form`

```
<?php

namespace MDB\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('name')
                ->add('nbEtoile')
                ->add('dateInscription')
                ->add('dateNaissance')
                ->add('adresse', new \MDB\AdresseBundle\Form\AdresseType())
                ->add('save', 'submit')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MDB\UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'mdb_userbundle_user';
    }

     public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

}
```

`MDB/src/UserBundle/Resources/config/service.yml`

```
services:
    mdb_user.registration.form.type:
        class: MDB\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: mdb_user_registration }

    mdb_user.registration_complet:
        class: MDB\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
        arguments: ["@router"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

    mdb_user.user.form.type:
        class: MDB\UserBundle\Form\Type\UserType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: mdb_userbundle_user }
```

`app/config/config.yml`

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm                       # Le type de BDD à utiliser, nous utilisons l'ORM Doctrine depuis le début
    firewall_name: main                      # Le nom du firewall derrière lequel on utilisera ces utilisateurs
    user_class:    MDB\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: mdb_user_registration
            type: mdb_userbundle_user
```

`UserController.php`

```
 public function editAction(Request $request) {
        if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            $session = $request->getSession();
            $session->getFlashBag()->add('errorRole', 'Vous devez être connecté pour accéder à cette page');
            return $this->render('MDBPlatformBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
        }

        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserEditType(), $user);

        if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->flush();
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profil bien modifiée.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mdb_platform_homepage'));
        }
        return $this->render('MDBUserBundle::editForm.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

Everything is ok, except this point.

Comment: *it doesn't work* What happens? Is there an error message?

Comment: There is no error. I can change my password only one time by user. If a try a second time , the form wil save all fields except the new password ( but without displaying any error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , i have found a small hack. It seems that i cant save the password if there is no change in the User entity. So i created a date type field "`dateOfProfilEdit`" and actualize it in my controller each time i save the form.

Hope it will helps